# Glide.js slider not pausing on last slide

Tags: javascript, glidejs

What i am trying to achieve, is a basic slideshow that starts, gets to the last slide and stops. I am using Glide.js as it is so small and is really awesome however, with the below code it does not actually pause and the slide spins round back to the beginning again.

```
/**
 * Homepage Slideshow
 */
if(document.querySelector('.glide')) {
    var item_length = document.querySelectorAll('.glide__slide').length - 1;
    let glide = new Glide('.glide', {
        type: 'slider',
        startAt: 0,
        perView: 1,
        autoplay: 6000,
        hoverpause: true,
    });

    glide.on('move', (e) => { 
        if(glide.index == item_length) {
            console.log(glide.index, item_length);
            glide.pause();  
        }
    });

    glide.mount();
}
```

I am getting the `console.log` out which is telling me `5 5` meaning I am on the `glide.index` at the 5th slide and the `item_length` is 5. So the `glide.pause()` should work. Any help would be greatly appreciated I have been scratching my head for ages on this. I have tried `run` and other events instead of move and still no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the rewind option to false:

```js
/**
 * Homepage Slideshow
 */
if(document.querySelector('.glide')) {
    var item_length = document.querySelectorAll('.glide__slide').length - 1;
    let glide = new Glide('.glide', {
        type: 'slider',
        startAt: 0,
        perView: 1,
        autoplay: 6000,
        hoverpause: true,
        rewind: false,
    });


    glide.mount();
}
```

[Reference](https://glidejs.com/docs/options/#rewind)

Comment: I didnt see this option.. Thanks soo much! :face_palm